# Playing multiple videos stored on raw folder one by one in videoview with different iterators?

Tags: java, android

I'm facing a problem while working with java android videoview.
My problem statement is User will input a sentence and i need to play the videos of each word one after another. And if the word video is not available in dataset then play a video of its each alphabet.
Well i figured a way to play the video of words present in dataset one after the other (thanks to stackoverflow) but now the problem i am facing is when the word is not available in the dataset.
I use if else statements but it's not working.

```
    else if( code == 3){
        sentence = getIntent().getStringExtra("sentence");
        tokens = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("tokens");
        COUNT = tokens.size();

        if(dataset.containsKey(tokens.get(iter))){
            videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + tokens.get(0)));
            videoView.requestFocus();
            head.setText(sentence);
            tail.setText(tokens.get(0));
            iter++;
        }else{
            videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
            alphaword = String.valueOf(tokens.get(iter));
            Toast.makeText(this, ""+(alphaword.charAt(ater)), LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(dataset.get(String.valueOf(alphaword.charAt(ater)))));
            ater++;
        }

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if(iter == COUNT) iter = 0;
                if(ater == alphaword.length()) {alphaword = "";iter++;}
                if(dataset.containsKey(tokens.get(iter))){
                    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(dataset.get(tokens.get(iter))));
                    tail.setText(tokens.get(iter));
                    iter++;
                }
                if( !alphaword.isEmpty() || !dataset.containsKey(tokens.get(iter))){
                    Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, ""+String.valueOf(alphaword.charAt(ater)), LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(dataset.get(String.valueOf(alphaword.charAt(ater)))));
                }
                ater++;
            }
        });
        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                videoView.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```